# Saxon serializer options with custom result document handler

Tags: .net, xslt, saxon

Hi I implemented a custom result document handler to resolve relative uris and keep track of written files.

```
private class ResultDocumentHandler : IResultDocumentHandler
{
    private List<string> writtenFiles = new List<string>();

    public List<string> WrittenFiles => this.writtenFiles;

    public XmlDestination HandleResultDocument(string href, Uri baseUri)
    {
        if (href.Contains("%"))
            href = Uri.UnescapeDataString(href);

        try
        {
            Uri hrefUri = new Uri(href, true);

            if (hrefUri.IsAbsoluteUri)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(hrefUri.LocalPath));

                Serializer serializer = new Serializer();

                serializer.SetOutputFile(hrefUri.LocalPath);
                writtenFiles.Add(hrefUri.LocalPath);

                return serializer;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignore
        }

        try
        {
            Uri absoluteUri = new Uri(baseUri, href, true);

            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(absoluteUri.LocalPath));

            Serializer serializer = new Serializer();

            serializer.SetOutputFile(absoluteUri.LocalPath);
            writtenFiles.Add(absoluteUri.LocalPath);

            return serializer;
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignore
        }

        return new NullDestination();
    }
}
```

So far so good. But as I create a new serializer it won't use the options that are given inside the xsl file. For example I used this:

```
<xsl:result-document href="{$resultDoc}" method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no">
```

These options are now ignored because I don't set them for the serializer. But how can I access them inside the result document handler? I guess I could access the options for `xsl:output` with `Saxon.Api.XsltTransformer.GetOutputProperties()` but I need those of the specific `xsl:result-document`.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any easy way to achieve this. I've logged this at

https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3153

What you can do is to ignore the ResultDocumentHandler mechanism in the Saxon.Api package, and drop down to the Java-defined OutputURIResolver. You can write a C# class that implements the OutputURIResolver interface and returns a StreamResult, and set this on the Controller interface that underpins the XsltTransformer. It's fiddly, because you'll have to add both the saxon9 DLL and some of the IKVM DLLs to your project so that you can program against the IKVM-supplied C# conversions of the underlying Java APIs. I guess that's why we added the ResultDocumentHandler interface, but we didn't think carefully enough about the use cases.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Maybe I try your suggestion later. Good to know that this is now tracked and will be fixed in the future. I look forward to it.